# Динамическое редактирование ячеек

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью JS можно сделать динамическое редактирование ячеек HTML таблицы?

Суть в чем, данные в таблицу заполняются из БД, и мне бы хотелось сделать так, что бы не заходя в БД я мог редактировать ячейки (которые записывались в БД). Ну знаете, как при работе с phpMyAdmin, 2 раза кликаешь на ячейку, редактируешь значения, затем жмешь Enter или в любом другом месте и все сохраняется.

Comment: Я для таких задач использовал Ajax Inline 1 в 1 как в phpMyAdmin
Подробнее о нем можете прочитать [здесь](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

`double-click` на ячейке - редактируем. `Enter` или потеря фокуса (`blur`) - отправка на сервер текстового содержимого ячейки. `/path/to/handler.php` - путь к обработчику, изменить на свой.

```js
const send = (e) => {
  if ((e.type === 'blur' && e.target.contentEditable === 'true') || e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.contentEditable = false;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/path/to/handler.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(`text=${encodeURIComponent(e.target.textContent)}`);
  }
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('td')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
    e.target.contentEditable = true;
    e.target.focus();
  });

  el.addEventListener('keypress', send);
  el.addEventListener('blur', send);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td:not([contenteditable=true]) {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

я бы советовал [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/)
у них есть хорошо документированный API в т.ч. с примерами для серверной обработки изменений.
а так, если в лоб, то навешиваете, например, атрибут contenteditable="true" на каждую ячейку таблицы с данными, а также js обработчик на изменение ячеек, который с помощью ajax отправляет измененные данные на Ваш php-скрипт, который и вносит изменения в базе.

Answer (score 0):

Не сложно, сначала Вам необходимо взять изменяемое значение в span.

Вот пример:

```html
<span onclick="handle(this)">My Name</span>

<script>
function handle(object){
     var inp = document.createElement("input");
     inp.type = "text";
     inp.value = object.innerText;

     object.innerText = "";
     object.appendChild(inp);
     
     var _event = object.onclick;
     object.onclick = null;

     inp.onkeydown = function(e){

         if(e.keyCode === 13){
               object.innerText = inp.value;
               object.onclick = _event;
               object.removeChild(inp);
         }

     };

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего использовать для такой задачи не чистый JS, а какой то JS Framework.
Я бы посоветовал Vue JS. Всё реактивное и сможете повесить обработчики событий при изменении полей будет отправляться AJAX запрос и всё будет сохраняться в базу.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это красиво, но я делал генерацию формы на каждую строку таблицы. Делал submit скрытым, а если происходили изменения, то submit показывался. Ну а дальше просто ajax-ом отправлял обработчику данные строки и скрывал submit снова